# RxJS retry not behaving as expected?

Tags: javascript, rxjs, reactive-programming

I'm having some difficulty getting RxJS' retry operator to work in combination with the map operator.

Essentially what I'm trying to do is take a stream of values (in this case GitHub users for testing purposes), and for each value do some operation on that value.

However I want to be able to handle errors in a way that allows me to set a finite number of retries for that operation. I'm also assuming RxJS handles such a thing asynchronously.

```
Rx.Observable.fromPromise(jQuery.getJSON("https://api.github.com/users"))
.concatAll(x => Rx.Observable.of(x))
.map(x => {
    if(x.id % 5 == 0) {
        console.log("error");
        return Rx.Observable.throw("error");
    }
    return x;
})
.retry(3)
.subscribe(x => console.log(x), e => console.log(e));
```

This is what I've got so far, however where it should retry the same value 3 times it only prints "error" once which isn't the behaviour I'm looking for.

Am I missing something trivial or if this sort of thing simply not possible with RxJS? In short I would like to execute operations on values asynchronously, retying said operation a finite number of times but allowing other valid operations to continue in parallel. I have achieved something similar using only promises but the code is rather messy and I was hoping RxJS would allow me to make things a bit nicer to read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit - removing earlier failed solutions for clarity (some comments may no longer be relevent)**

To retry individual failures, you need to break to individual requests and retry those.

To allow proper handling of errors, split the streams into sub-streams for each expected outcome.

I've also added a bit of code to allow one of the retries to suceed.

```
const Observable = Rx.Observable

// Define tests here, allow requestAgain() to pass one
const testUser = (user) => user.id % 5 !== 0
const testUserAllowOneSuccess = (user) => user.id === 5 || user.id % 5 !== 0

const requestAgain = (login) => Observable.of(login)
  .switchMap(login => jQuery.getJSON("https://api.github.com/users/" + login ))
  .map(x => {
    if(!testUserAllowOneSuccess(x)) {
      console.log("logging error retry attempt", x.id);
      throw new Error('Invalid user: ' + x.id)
    }
    return x;
  })
  .retry(3)
  .catch(error => Observable.of(error))

const userStream = Observable.fromPromise(jQuery.getJSON("https://api.github.com/users"))
  .concatAll()

const passed = userStream.filter(x => testUser(x))
const failed = userStream.filter(x => !testUser(x))
  .flatMap(x => requestAgain(x.login))

const retryPassed = failed.filter(x => !(x instanceof Error))
const retryFailed = failed.filter(x => (x instanceof Error))
  .toArray()
  .map(errors => { throw errors })

const output = passed.concat(retryPassed, retryFailed)

output.subscribe(
  x=> console.log('subscribe next', x.id ? x.id : x), 
  e => console.log('subscribe error', e)
);
```

Working example [CodePen](https://codepen.io/RMatsen/pen/PJxpGP)

Comment: Perfect, this is exactly the sort of solution I was looking for. Many thanks!

Comment: I've done some further testing with this solution and seem to be running into some strange issues. When refreshing the cache in chrome it won't attempt to get all of the users, only about 5 or 6 after refreshing the page it will then decide to get all approximately 40 users (or however large the page size is for the api). Another thing I'm unsure about is that the error message "Invalid User" only displays once regardless of how many actually fail.

Comment: Indeed. I'm wondering if the the asynchrony of the events, rather than caching, is causing it. My theory is the error throw for id #5 (after n retries) stops the main sequence dead. Usually, the main list gets output entirely because it's in memory and can beat the 3 HTTP `requestAgain` calls, but sometimes not. So it seems we need an alternative to `throw`.

Comment: Also, when the truncation occurs I see #3 is missing and #4 is delayed in the sequence. I would expect the successful items to occur in sequence.

Comment: Further thought, throwing an error is definitely the wrong way of handling errors. The basic definition of an observable stream is that it emits until error or complete, and the retries are part of the main sequence, due to `return x` inside the map, which is required in case the retry attempt succeeds. This probably also means that `.retry()` cant be used for the retry mechanism.

Comment: I've made some progress by altering your code slightly, I'm still throwing an error but instead if all 3 retries fail I'm catching the error and returning the value of the error. I've run it several times and haven't yet ran into the issue on chrome, I've been manually deleting all cached objects after each test as well. What I dislike about this approach though, is that I'm having to handle the thrown errors inside the 'next' function of the subscriber, doing something along the lines of "(if x instanceof Error)".

Comment: So at the moment it's able to retry all of the request that should fail, and output an error when a request fails n times. Again, I'm not a fan of handling the errors in the next function though.

Comment: As mentioned, that's Rx 101 - if the subscriber sees a value in the error function, the stream stops. To handle this, I believe we need a different error trapping mechanism. BTW, I'm getting `undefined` for the 'error' outputs in the next stream. What is your catch code?

Comment: Well, the idea of not using the retry operator is off-putting, and I'd rather just go back to using Promises if that were the case, since I'm assuming that NOT throwing an error would make the retry operator obsolete in this instance. Also I simply appended "catch(error => Rx.Observable.of(error));" after the call to retry and I also removed the outputting of the id in the next function "x.id", that's probably why you're getting the undefined error.

Comment: It is solvable, just needs a bit of thought. I was playing with the idea of 'pass' and 'fail' streams in the main fetch, which models your requirements better. The trick is to gather all errors and emit them at the end with something like concat.

Comment: Interesting. See the way I solved it previously using promises was to check some condition, like we're doing now with the modulo operator and if that condition failed, recursively call the promise passing in a variable that kept track of the number of tries thus far and it worked rather well, however this was only possible due to how promises handle chained promises. Maybe the same functionality would be possible with something like expand?

Comment: Cool, I was going to ask for a look at the Promise solution.

Comment: Very nice idea to use filter, thanks for you help :)

Answer (score 2):

I see a couple issues that are probably causing you problems:

1) In your map statement, you're doing the throw by returning an observable. This would be appropriate if the success case was also returning an observable which you were then flattening (with concat, switch, or merge), but instead your success case just emits a value and never flattens. So when that Throw observable is returned, it never gets flattened, and thus just gets passed through and the observable object is logged.

Instead, you can just do a plain javascript `throw 'error'` (though consider throwing an error object instead of a string)

2) When retry gets an error, it will resubscribe. If you're using observables to do your fetching, this will mean that it will make the fetch again. However, you did the fetching with a promise, and then only created an observable from that promise. So when you resubscribe to the observable, it will end up using the very same promise object that it did the first time, and that promise is already in a resolved state. No additional fetch will be made.

To fix this, you'll need to have an observable version of doing the fetch. If you need to make this from scratch, it could look like this:

```
Rx.Observable.create(observer => {
  jQuery.getJSON("https://api.github.com/users")
    .then(result => {
      observer.next(result);
      observer.complete();
    }, err => {
      observer.error(err);
      observer.complete();
    });
})
```

Though if you intend to do this often, i recommend creating a function that does that wrapping for you.

EDIT:

> My end goal with this is to essentially be able to take an array of api urls, and initiate get requests with each URL. If a get request fails for whatever reason, it should try a total 3 times to reach that endpoint again. However, the failing of such a get request should not inhibit the other requests from taking place, they should be happening in parallel. Furthermore if a get request fails 3 times, it should just be marked as failed and it should not stop the process as a whole. So far I've not found a way of doing so using RxJS.

Then i would do something like this:

```
function getJson (url) {
  return Rx.Observable.create(observer) => {
    jQuery.getJSON(url)
      .then(result => {
        observer.next(result);
        observer.complete();
      }, err => {
        observer.error(err);
        observer.complete();
      });
  }
}

const endpoints = ['someUrl', 'someOtherUrl'];
const observables = endpoints.map(endpoint => 
  return getJson(url)
    .retry(3)
    .catch(err => Rx.Observable.of('error'));
});

Rx.Observable.forkJoin(...observables)
  .subscribe(resultArray => {
    // do whatever you need to with the results. If any of them
    //   errored, they will be represented by just the string 'error'
  });
```

Comment: My end goal with this is to essentially be able to take an array of api urls, and initiate get requests with each URL. If a get request fails for whatever reason, it should try a total 3 times to reach that endpoint again. However, the failing of such a get request should not inhibit the other requests from taking place, they should be happening in parallel. Furthermore if a get request fails 3 times, it should just be marked as failed and it should not stop the process as a whole. So far I've not found a way of doing so using RxJS.

Comment: I edited in a proposal based on your latest description

Comment: I had to modify the code you provided slightly to get it to behave how I wanted but it works great :)

Answer (score 1):

Your map function returns `Rx.Observable.throw("error");`. It is wrong, because the following `retry()` will then receive it wrapped (i.e. as `Observable<Observable<T>>` instead of `Observable<T>`. You can use `flatMap` to correct that, but then you also need to wrap the value via `Rx.Observable.of(x)`.

```
.flatMap(x => {
    if(x % 5 == 0) {
        console.log("error");
        return Rx.Observable.throw("error");
    }
    return Rx.Observable.of(x);
})
.retry(3)
.subscribe(x => console.log(x), e => console.log(e));
```

Another option is to `throw new Error()` instead of trying to `return Rx.Observable.throw("error");`

---

Make sure you retry on the right thing

```
Rx.Observable.fromPromise(jQuery.getJSON("https://api.github.com/users"))
  .retry(3)
  .concatAll(x => Rx.Observable.of(x))
  ...
```

Comment: I see, but another problem arises. When the retry is initiated it starts the entire observable again, which means retrieving all the users and never getting past the 5th user. What I'm trying to do is act on only a single user, so that when retrying only the code in the flatMap function is executed and not the entire observable code. For example, some operation on user with an Id of 5 fails, the other users should continue to be operated on whilst the user that failed should keep retrying until it hits 3 retries. Again, I don't know if this is even possible with RxJS, but it is with promises.

Comment: @samcp20 it's because you're retrying on whole bunch of observables. Instead, retry on exactly what you expect to fail. See the updated code where `retry` immediately follows `fromPromise` (before `concatAll` is given a chance to spawn many new observables).

Comment: Moving the retry operator still doesn't achieve what I'm trying to do. I essentially need each operation (the if(x.id % 5 == 0) code in this example) to be some separate task completely that can be retried but is independent from the other operations. If one operation fails I don't want the entire observable to stop processing, it should simply output an error for that user. In short each Observable that is spawned should be retried on its own, whilst allowing the other Observablea to continue processing and 3 failures should not stop the entire data stream.

Answer (score 0):

Then convert promise with `from` is not repeatable

Example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-dp3md8

But, with `Observable.create` works well

If somebody have solution to make promise repeatable, please post comment.